# How to set PATH on Windows through R "shell" command

Tags: windows, r, git, shell, path

I wish to add git to my PATH in Windows 7, through the "shell" command in R.

```
shell('set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\\Program%20Files%20(x86)\\Git\\bin"', intern = TRUE)
shell("echo %PATH% ", intern= TRUE)
```

But I do not see that path added.

If I run the above code in cmd.exe, it does add it to PATH.

Any idea what is the issue?

UPDATE:
I ended up manually running the following through cmd.exe (which I made sure to run as admin)

```
setx PATH "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin"
```

Which worked. But I wish I could have done so through R. (maybe create a temp file and run it?)
I then had to restart some programs to make sure they had been affected.

Comment: What does `shell('set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\\Program%20Files%20(x86)\\Git\\bin"', shell = NULL, intern = TRUE)` give?

Comment: Error in basename(shell) : a character vector argument expected

Comment: So, it doesn't work. Sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to permanantly update your path, then you pretty much had the answer:

```
shell('setx PATH "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin"')
```

R only notes a copy of the Windows environment variables when it starts up though, so `strsplit(Sys.getenv("PATH"), ";")` won't be different until you restart R.

Also, this won't run as with admin permissions (unless you set R as an administrator?) so it will add the path to the *user* path variable not the system one.

---

If you want R to see a different path in the current session, just use `Sys.setenv`.

```
Sys.setenv(
  PATH = paste(
    Sys.getenv("PATH"), 
    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin", 
    sep = ";"
  )
)
```

This won't make permanant changes to the path.  Only R can see this change, and only until you close it.

Comment: Thanks Richie (I missed you at this year's useR)

Answer (score 3):

When you run `shell`, a new process is created.  In Windows, this will run `CMD.EXE` and pass the arguments given.  Then this process exits.

When you modify the environment variable, you are modifying in a subprocess of R and not in the R process itself.  When the subprocess dies, so does its environment.

You should set the path appropriately before you start R instead.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> **”** what is the issue?

You're just changing the PATH environment variable in the new command interpreter process.

---

You can use the `setx` command to change the PATH defaults, but that does not affect your current process.

What to do depends a bit on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Cheers. I tried it but it failed. Here is an example code:
--------------
shell("setx PATH=%PATH%;C:/xampp/php")
--------------
I get:
------
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
Type "SETX /?" for usage.
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c setx PATH=%PATH%;C:/xampp/php' had status 1 
2: In shell("setx PATH=%PATH%;C:/xampp/php") :
  'setx PATH=%PATH%;C:/xampp/php' execution failed with error code 1