# How to add a search path to R?

Tags: r, search-path, pymol

In [this tutorial](http://thegrantlab.org/bio3d/tutorials/trajectory-analysis), there is a command `pymol.dccm(cij, pdb, type="launch")`. But I was told

```
> pymol.dccm(cij, pdb, type="launch")
Error in pymol.dccm(cij, pdb, type = "launch") : 
  Launching external program failed
  make sure 'C:/python27/PyMOL/pymol.exe' is in your search path
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'C:/python27/PyMOL/pymol.exe -cq' had status 127
```

I already have `pymol` installed on my PC. Can I ask how to add another search path to R?

Now I think `pymol` is a sub-package in `bio3d`. But I already installed `bio3d` and other commands can work (e.g. `pdb <- read.pdb()`). But why the `pymol` command could not work?

---

I tried

`> .libPaths("path/to/pymol2/")`

`> .libPaths("path/to/pymol2/PyMOL")`

```
> .libPaths("path/to/pymol2/PyMOL/PyMOLWin.exe")

> pymol.dccm(cij, pdb, type="launch")
Error in pymol.dccm(cij, pdb, type = "launch") : 
  Launching external program failed
  make sure 'C:/python27/PyMOL/pymol.exe' is in your search path
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'C:/python27/PyMOL/pymol.exe -cq' had status 127 

> PyMOLWin.dccm(cij, pdb, type="launch")
Error: could not find function "PyMOLWin.dccm"
```

So the `.libPaths` did not return error. But `pymol.dccm` and `PyMOLWin.dccm` did not work.

---

I also tried to install `pymol` package in `R`

```
> install.packages("pymol")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘pymol’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)
```

Comment: `.libPaths` only influences where R looks for packages, not where it looks for executables. You'll want to set the PATH system variable. See this question for how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622725/how-to-set-path-on-windows-through-r-shell-command

Comment: I have `PyMOLWin.exe` executable, but where is the `pymol` package?

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake in the tutorial command itself. The correct syntax for dccm is

```
pymol(cij, pdb, type="launch",exefile="C:/Program Files/pymol")
```

where `exefile = file path` to the ‘PYMOL’ program on your system (i.e. how is ‘PYMOL’ invoked). If NULL, use OS-dependent default path to the program.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, it worked perfectly for me:

```
pymol(cm, pdb.open, type="launch", exefile="%userprofile%/PyMOL/PyMOLWin.exe")
```

Answer (score -1):

[`.libPaths("path/to/package/library")`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/libPaths) probably does what you need.

> .libPaths gets/sets the library trees within which packages are looked for.

Set the path to the parent directory of the directory with the package name rather than the package directory itself.

Comment: I tried, but is there a specific `pymol` that `R` can recognise? Please see the updated question.

Comment: Did you try setting the path to the parent directory of that package folder you are trying to refer to?

Comment: The essential part is just about how to set the path in R. That is why I only use link to refer.

Comment: Jordi, could you please tell me what is the exact path, "path/to/pymol2/", or "path/to/pymol2/PyMOL"? As @MrFlick mentioned, is there a difference between package and executable?

Comment: @lanselibai, if it is like any R package, you should find a DESCRIPTION file somewhere. This is the package directory. Set the path to the parent of that package directory.