# RSelenium on rstudio Server; Firefox

Tags: r, selenium, firefox, rstudio, rselenium

I want to use RSelenium for web scraping, but ran into this problem when trying to connect to Firefox. Would appreciate any help.

```
 > rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox")
    checking Selenium Server versions:
    BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
    BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
    BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
    checking chromedriver versions:
    BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
    BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
    BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
    checking geckodriver versions:
    BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
    BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
    BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
    checking phantomjs versions:
    BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
    BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
    BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
    [1] "Connecting to remote server"
    
    Selenium message:Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
    Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
    System info: host: 'L90801', ip: '10.146.202.24', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_162'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    remote stacktrace: 
    
    Could not open firefox browser.
    Client error message:
         Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
         Detail: A new session could not be created.
         Further Details: run errorDetails method
    Check server log for further details.
```

Comment: Have you taken a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65322308/9494044)?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that it's python, and I'm working with R. I've tried to play with paths in RStudio, but nothing worked. If you could elaborate how I can pass an absolute path to Firefox with RSelenium, that would be nice.

Comment: Tried this approach, no result




`exCap <- list(
  "moz:firefoxOptions" = list(
    args = list('--headless'), 
    binary = list('--C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Mozilla Firefox\\\\firefox.exe')
  )
)
# and use it here
rD <- rsDriver(
  browser = "firefox",
  extraCapabilities = exCap
)`

@Dunois

Comment: There can be many reasons, update your firefox browser, update the java, install latest package, mention the `version` of firefox , mention the `port`.

Comment: Hm, are you using `Docker` with `RSelenium` as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45401318)? I don't think the `rsDriver` approach works at all.

Comment: @NadPat have done it multiple times, still the same error pops up

Comment: @Dunois I'm working on a PC w/o admin rights, so installing and running Docker is not possible for me, thus I chose rsDriver.

Comment: I've never been able to get `rsDriver` to work, so I'm not sure what other options you have here within `RSelenium`.

Comment: Consider adding firefox to Path variable, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622725/how-to-set-path-on-windows-through-r-shell-command https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43882307/where-should-i-set-the-variable-path-in-r https://community.rstudio.com/t/adding-to-the-path-variable/12066

Comment: @NadPat yeah, I did that

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine to me, remember, you will need to have java installed and set which one is your chromeover

in error message appears which ones is available for you

```
rd <- rsDriver(port = 4445L,browser = "chrome", chromever = "95.0.4638.54")
rem <- rd$client
rem$open()
```